# Adding each element in a 2d list to another 2d list in Python

Tags: python, list, 2d, element

So i need to define a function, in which i get 2 lists that are 2d. The goal is to add each element to each other.

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
list2 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

the result should be this:

```
   result = [[2,4,6], [8,10,12],[14,16,18]]
```

So far, i built this function:

```
def add_matrices(list1, list2):
    matrix = list1 + list2
    return matrix
```

But im kinda stuck now, I have tried to use append and extend, but both didn't work. I have found a few solutions that required the usage of numpy, which unfortunately isn't allowed for this. Can anybody please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: this would be a simple `list1 + list2` if they were numpy arrays

Answer (score 2):

One approach:

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
list2 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]


res = [[e1 + e2 for e1, e2 in zip(li1, li2)] for li1, li2 in zip(list1, list2)]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12], [14, 16, 18]]
```

Functional alternative using [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
from operator import add
res = [list(map(add, li1, li2)) for li1, li2 in zip(list1, list2)]
print(res)
```

**UPDATE**

If required to return `None` if any of the inner list do not match in length, do the following:

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
list2 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]


def list_sum(lst1, lst2):
    if any(len(e1) != len(e2) for e1, e2 in zip(lst1, lst2)):
        return None
    return [[e1 + e2 for e1, e2 in zip(li1, li2)] for li1, li2 in zip(list1, list2)]


print(list_sum(list1, list2))
print(list_sum([[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]))
```

**Output**

```
[[2, 4, 6], [8, 10, 12], [14, 16, 18]]
None
```

Comment: Thank you :) I also have another question regarding this, what if I want to return a None statement if the amount of elements in each 2d list are not equal? For example:            
list 1 = [[1,2], [4,5],[7,8]]                                                                                                          list 2 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

Comment: None for each sub list or for the whole output, which one [None, None, None] or None?

Comment: None for the whole output.

Comment: @sari023 Updated the answer!